# How to create multiple number inputs and update the dataframe when new entry is there using streamlit python?

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I am new to Streamlit and I am working on a problem where I am trying to create multiple number inputs based on the number of columns selected and number of values selected for number input. I am able to create number inputs as per columns selected and also the dataframe. But that dataframe is not being updated when I am entering any new number into the input field.

This is the code I am working on :

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

exogenous_features = ['Var1', 'Var2']
predict_size = 4
                    
cols = st.columns(len(exogenous_features))
lists = []
                
for p in range(len(exogenous_features)):
    lists.append([])
                    
for i, c in enumerate(cols):
    with c:
        for h in range(predict_size):
            a=st.number_input('',key=str(random.randint(0,100000)))
            lists[i].append(a)
                                
df= pd.DataFrame(lists)
df= bb.transpose()
df.columns = exogenous_features
st.write(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of your code.
**Note:** every new `st.number_input` must have a unique `key` otherwise you will always encounter `DuplicateWidgetID:` Error.

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

exogenous_features = ['Var1', 'Var2']
predict_size = 4
                    
cols = st.columns(len(exogenous_features))
lists = []
                
for p in range(len(exogenous_features)):
    lists.append([])
                    
for i, c in enumerate(cols):
    with c:
        for h in range(predict_size):
            key = f"number_input_{i}_{h}"
            a = st.number_input(exogenous_features[i], key=key)
            lists[i].append(a)
                                
df = pd.DataFrame(lists)
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = exogenous_features
st.write(df)
```

Output:

[image]